# SQL Query conditions with WHERE and AND

Tags: sql, oracle

I have query like this

```
SELECT EDR.DEPT_ID             AS DEPT_ID,
  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID                AS EMPLOYEE_ID,
  ELD.LOAN_ID                  AS LOAN_ID,
  ELD.LOAN_STATUS                       AS LOAN_STATUS
FROM EMP_DEPT_REL EDR
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE_MANUAL EMP
ON EDR.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_LOAN_DETAIL ELD
ON ELD.LOAN_ID   = EMP.LOAN_ID
AND ELD.DISPLAY_FLAG       = 'Y'
WHERE EDR.DEPT_ID IN ('123');
```

1. Employee_Manual is the table where we will have employee details which is been manually entered by the application.
2. Emp_dept_rel is the relationship between the employee and department.
3. Employee_loan_detail will have the loan details of all the employees in the organization.

I would like to get the data from of all the employees who are associated in the department, which I am passing as an input.

What I need is,

- Get all the employees who are in the employee_manual table.
- If there
  are entries in Employee_loan_details, then I should get details of
  the loan, only if the flag is set as "Y" in Employee_loan_details.
- We need to display the employees even if there are no details in
  Employee_loan_details

Need to get the  data of the employees who are having loans in a particular department. If Employee has a external loan, We need to show the loan detail.(DISPLAY_FLAG = 'Y') If it is a internal loan, provided by the organization, It will be in the Employee_loan_detail and it will marked as DISPLAY_FLAG = "N"

```
EMPLOYEE_LOAN_DETAIL
<table>
<tr><th>EMPLOYEE_ID</th><th>LOAD_ID</th><th>DISPLAY_FLAG</th><tr>
<tr><td>123</td><td>50</td><td>Y</td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td><td>51</td><td>N</td></tr>
<table>

emp_dept_rel 
<table>
<tr><th>EMP_ID</th><th>DEPT_ID</th><tr>
<tr><td>123</td><td>987</td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td><td>987</td></tr>
<tr><td>789</td><td>987</td></tr>
<table>

employee_manual 
<table>
<tr><th>EMPLOYEE_ID</th><th>LOAD_ID</th><th>DEPT_ID</th><tr>
<tr><td>123</td><td>50</td><td>987</td></tr>
<tr><td>456</td><td>51</td><td>987</td></tr>
<tr><td>789</td><td></td><td>987</td></tr>
<table>
```

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: Please show:  Table schema definitions, example table data, and expected output.

Comment: @Tatiana, I have mentioned the questions as conditions. Please throw some light on it

Comment: is this a homework ?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, Table Schema, 

table employee_manual 
EMPLOYEE_ID
LOAN_ID
DEPT_ID

table emp_dept_rel
EMP_ID
DEPT_ID

table employee_loan_detail
EMPLOYEE_ID
LOAN_ID
DISPLAY_FLAG

Comment: as first point you want like this ? `select EMPLOYEE_ID from  employee_manual`

Comment: I want data of the employees who are having loans in a particular department. 
If Employee has a external loan, We need to show the loan detail.(DISPLAY_FLAG = 'Y')
If it is a internal loan, provided by the organization, It will be in the Employee_loan_detail and it will marked as DISPLAY_FLAG = "N".

Comment: Don't post edits to your question as comments.  Please edit the question content.  Where is the sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  EDR.DEPT_ID             AS   DEPT_ID,
  EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID         AS   EMPLOYEE_ID,
  ELD.LOAN_ID             AS   LOAN_ID,
  ELD.LOAN_STATUS         AS   LOAN_STATUS

FROM        EMPLOYEE_MANUAL EMP

INNER JOIN  EMP_DEPT_REL EDR
            ON EDR.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID

LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE_LOAN_DETAIL ELD  
            ON ELD.LOAN_ID   = EMP.LOAN_ID

WHERE EDR.DEPT_ID IN ('123') AND ELD.DISPLAY_FLAG       = 'Y';
```

Comment: @Venkat please tell what problem are you facing. I mean which records are not showing up.